# Prove that for for an arbitrary linear operator all eigenvalues lie in a circular ring.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, singularity-theory

Prove that for for an arbitrary linear operator all eigenvalues lie in a circular ring.

{z $\in$ $С$ | $\sigma_n(A)$ $\leq$ $|z|$ $\leq \sigma_1(A)$}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that 
$$
\sigma_1(A) = \max_{\|x\| = 1}  \|Ax\|, \quad \sigma_n(A) = \min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|.
$$

Comment: Okay, now we know that the module of a complex number lies between the maximum and minimum singular number. What is the relationship with the operator's eigenvalues?

Comment: @Spectra2001 To reframe your question in a straightforward fashion: what is the relationship between $\|Ax\|$ and the modulus of the eigenvalues of $A$? Try to figure this out on your own